Which Set Diagram Can represent XOR properly?
the problem confuses me may be a little stupid,
the below set diagrams represent my understanding of XOR,
first_figure, second_figure
After looking at pictures online, I see that most visualizations of XOR use the second set diagram. This aligns with my understanding of XOR as well.
While many online visualizations decipt XOR using the second set diagram, the first diagram might be more suitable for understanding XOR in the context of binary operations. This is because the first diagram directy represents the bit-wise operation where a '1' results only if exactly one of the input bits is a '1'

How are we to interpret either figure? What is your understanding of each?
